# How to convert CSV file in array to MongoDB using python for this application

Tags: python, arrays, sql-server, mongodb, export-to-csv

[image]

[image]

I am trying to convert Applications column in array as i have marked in screenshot. The problem i am facing through this process is converting CSV file data in array to mongodb. I am using python language to work with database.

Currently:

```
{'Applications': 'Chrysler 200 2014-2011, Cirrus 2009-2006, Cirrus (Mex) 2008-2006, Sebring 2010-2007, Town & Country 2010-2001, Voyager 1999-1996, Voyager 2008-2001, Voyager (Mex) 1999-1996, Voyager (Mex) 2002-2001, Voyager (Mex) 2008-2004, Dodge Avenger 2014-2008, Caravan 2007-2001, Grand Caravan 2010-2001, Volkswagen Routan 2010-2009, Routan Exclusive (Mex) 2010, Routan Prestige (Mex) 2010'}
```

Expecting (in array):

```
{'Applications': [Chrysler 200 2014-2011, Cirrus 2009-2006, Cirrus (Mex) 2008-2006, Sebring 2010-2007, Town & Country 2010-2001, Voyager 1999-1996, Voyager 2008-2001, Voyager (Mex) 1999-1996, Voyager (Mex) 2002-2001, Voyager (Mex) 2008-2004, Dodge Avenger 2014-2008, Caravan 2007-2001, Grand Caravan 2010-2001, Volkswagen Routan 2010-2009, Routan Exclusive (Mex) 2010, Routan Prestige (Mex) 2010']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this what you are looking for but I guess the `Application` is the key for the string `'Chrysler 200 2014-2011,............`.

You could just read the value of Application and then split it with `','` delimiter to get the list of elements in the array in python, as shown in the below code and convert the string into array in python.

Code:

```
data =  {'Applications': 'Chrysler 200 2014-2011, Cirrus 2009-2006, Cirrus (Mex) 2008-2006, Sebring 2010-2007, Town & Country 2010-2001, Voyager 1999-1996, Voyager 2008-2001, Voyager (Mex) 1999-1996, Voyager (Mex) 2002-2001, Voyager (Mex) 2008-2004, Dodge Avenger 2014-2008, Caravan 2007-2001, Grand Caravan 2010-2001, Volkswagen Routan 2010-2009, Routan Exclusive (Mex) 2010, Routan Prestige (Mex) 2010'}

arr = data['Applications'].split(',') 

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['Chrysler 200 2014-2011', ' Cirrus 2009-2006', ' Cirrus (Mex) 2008-2006', ' Sebring 2010-2007', ' Town & Country 2010-2001', ' Voyager 1999-1996', ' Voyager 2008-2001', ' Voyager (Mex) 1999-1996', ' Voyager (Mex) 2002-2001', ' Voyager (Mex) 2008-2004', ' Dodge Avenger 2014-2008', ' Caravan 2007-2001', ' Grand Caravan 2010-2001', ' Volkswagen Routan 2010-2009', ' Routan Exclusive (Mex) 2010', ' Routan Prestige (Mex) 2010']
```

Note: I am not sure this is what you wanted. But hope this helps.